# Expo Securestore. Can't save userid and token after auth

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am trying to save userId and token in securestore. On the next screen I can get token from securestore, but I can't see userid

```
  const doUserLogIn = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://someurl-dev.de/api/login/?email='+email+'&password='+password, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      SecureStore.setItemAsync('userid', json.userId);
      SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', json.token);
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Error1:'+e);
    } finally {
      try{
        navigation.navigate('Schichten');
      } catch(e) {alert('Error2:'+e); }
    }
  }
```

And here's the json returned by api call

```
{"userId":9,"token":"957a230f3eb6e63c47f1d7a0805fe31df6d2ced7","vorname":"Ankit","nachname":"Vij"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting the async functions `setItemAsync`. You should try the following:

```
await SecureStore.setItemAsync('userid', json.userId);
await SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', json.token);
```

Additionally, you can try to log the value of the `json` variable to make sure that it does contain the `userId` and `token` properties.